# Centering the x-axis label under the plot area

Tags: plotting, labeling

I have the following code:

```
adata = {{2.`, 2.977288135593221`}, {3.`, 5.057966101694916`}, {4.`, 9.12474576271186`}, {4.954196310386875`, 18.`}, {5.977279923499916`, 31.`}, {6.965784284662088`, 51.494915254237284`}, {7.965784284662086`, 76.4315254237288`}, {8.965784284662087`, 95.`}}

bdata = {{2.`, 2.`}, {3.`, 3.`}, {4.`, 8.`}, {4.954196310386875`, Around[18., 4.]}, {5.977279923499916`, Around[31., 8.]}, {6.965784284662088`, Around[53., 3.]}, {7.965784284662086`, Around[75., 4.]}, {8.965784284662087`, Around[88., 2.]}}

Labeled[Show[{ListLinePlot[{adata, bdata}, IntervalMarkers -> "Fences", PlotMarkers -> {Graphics[{Disk[], {Thick, Circle[]}}], 0.04}, Ticks -> {{{2, 4}, {3, 8}, {4, 16}, {5, 31}, {6, 63}, {7, 125}, {8, 250}, {9, 500}}, {{20, "20%"}, {40, "40%"}, {60, "60%"}, {80, "80%"}, {100, "100%"}}}, LabelStyle -> {22, GrayLevel[0]}, PlotStyle -> {{RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], Thick}, {RGBColor[0.922526, 0.385626, 0.209179], Thick}}, BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math"}, PlotLegends -> {Style["Simulation", FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math"], Style["Experiment", FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math"]}]}, ImageSize -> Large], {Rotate[Style["% Cells", FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math"], 90 Degree], Style["MOI", FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math"]}, {Left, Bottom}, LabelStyle -> {22, GrayLevel[0]}]
```

which produces:

[image]

How can I position the x-axis label "MOI" to be exactly at the center of the plot area? Currently it appears skewed a bit to the right because it is centered with respect to the entire graphic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
Column[{
  Labeled[
   ListLinePlot[{adata, bdata}, IntervalMarkers -> "Fences", 
    PlotMarkers -> {Graphics[{Disk[], {Thick, Circle[]}}], 0.04}, 
    Ticks -> {{{2, 4}, {3, 8}, {4, 16}, {5, 31}, {6, 63}, {7, 
        125}, {8, 250}, {9, 500}}, {{20, "20%"}, {40, "40%"}, {60, 
        "60%"}, {80, "80%"}, {100, "100%"}}}, 
    LabelStyle -> {22, GrayLevel[0]}, 
    PlotStyle -> {{RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], 
       Thick}, {RGBColor[0.922526, 0.385626, 0.209179], Thick}}, 
    BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math"}, 
    PlotLegends -> {Style["Simulation", 
       FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math"], 
      Style["Experiment", FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math"]}, 
    ImageSize -> Large], {Rotate[
     Style["% Cells", FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math"], 90 Degree], 
    Style["", 6]}, {Left, Bottom}, LabelStyle -> {22, GrayLevel[0]}],
  Row[{Spacer[300], 
    Graphics[{Text[
       Style["MOI", 20, FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math"]]}]}]
  }, Spacings -> -3.5]
```

does what you want if I understood you right. Have a look:

[image]

Play a bit with the argument of `Spacer[]` to adjust the position of "MOI."

The displacement of the position of the bottom label is because of the use of the PlotLegend. That is, the position of "MOI" is in the center if you take the size of the plot together with the size of the legend into account.

I would do such a plot differently: see below

```
ListLinePlot[{adata, bdata}, IntervalMarkers -> "Fences", 
 Frame -> True, 
 PlotMarkers -> {Graphics[{Disk[], {Thick, Circle[]}}], 0.04}, 
 LabelStyle -> {22, GrayLevel[0]}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], 
    Thick}, {RGBColor[0.922526, 0.385626, 0.209179], Thick}}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math"},
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[PointLegend[{Style["Simulation", 
      FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math"], 
     Style["Experiment", FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math"]}, 
    LegendFunction -> "Frame"], Scaled[{0.2, 0.77}]], 
 ImageSize -> Large,
 FrameLabel -> {Style["MOI", FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math"], 
   Style["% Cells", FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math"]},
 FrameTicks -> {{{{20, "20%"}, {40, "40%"}, {60, "60%"}, {80, 
      "80%"}, {100, "100%"}}, 
    None}, {{{2, 4}, {3, 8}, {4, 16}, {5, 31}, {6, 63}, {7, 125}, {8, 
      250}, {9, 500}}, None}}
 ]
```

which yields the following plot:

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: I use 12.0. Maybe, this is due to their differences. Check `PlotLegends`,  `Placed` and `LegendFunction` in your version to see if there is something new in them.

Answer (score 3):

Add to your ticks:

`{5.5, Style["\nMOI", FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math"], {0, 0}}`

and remove the label from the other location.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could use Frame

[image: Mathematica graphics]

code

```
leftticks = {{20, "20%"}, {40, "40%"}, {60, "60%"}, {80, "80%"}, {100,"100%"}};
bottomticks = { {2, 4}, {3, 8}, {4, 16}, {5, 31}, {6, 63}, {7, 125}, {8, 250}, {9, 500}};

leftLabel = Style["% Cells", FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math"];    
bottomLabel = Style["MOI", FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math"];

ListLinePlot[{adata, bdata}, IntervalMarkers -> "Fences",
 PlotMarkers -> {Graphics[{Disk[], {Thick, Circle[]}}], 0.04}, 
 LabelStyle -> {22, GrayLevel[0]}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], 
    Thick}, {RGBColor[0.922526, 0.385626, 0.209179], Thick}}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math"}, 
 PlotLegends -> {Style["Simulation", 
    FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math"], 
   Style["Experiment", FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math"]},
 ImageSize -> Large,
 FrameTicks -> {{leftticks, None} , {bottomticks, None}},
 FrameLabel -> {{leftLabel, None}, {bottomLabel, None}},
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}
 ]
```