# Aligning text on a graph

Tags: plotting, graphics

I would like to align the reduced temperature text Tr below the x-axis and not align it to the whole graph. The code used so far is this

```
graficoTr =   Labeled[   ListPlot[    Table[{dataPerCompound[[i, All, 9]], 
      dataPerCompound[[i, All, 2]]}\[Transpose], {i, 
     Length[compoundNameRight]}],    PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[
     PointLegend[colours1, Style[#, par1] & /@ compoundNameRight, 
      LegendMarkers -> markers, LegendLayout -> {"Column", 3}], 
     Right], PlotMarkers -> Evaluate[{#, par2} & /@ markers],     PlotStyle -> colours1, ImageSize -> 500,     Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, FrameStyle -> 15,     PlotRange -> All], {Rotate[
    Style[
     "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Sigma]\), \ \(exp\)]\)(N\[CenterDot]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(m\), \(-1\)]\))", 15], 
    90 Degree],     Style[Row[{Style["Tr", 15]}], ScriptBaselineShifts -> {0, .5}, 
    SingleLetterItalics -> False, "TraditionalForm"]}, {Left, Bottom},    FrameMargins -> {{-8, 0}, {0, 0}}]
```

And the result is this one
[image: Result]

Comment: You can do that using `FrameLabel` as in: `FrameLabel->{Style["x label"],Rotate[Style["y label"],90 Degree]}`

Comment: Would [275363](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275360/centering-the-x-axis-label-under-the-plot-area/275363#275363) be of some help?

Comment: @josh Thanks a lot! It works very well!

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your data, we cannot experiment with your code. However, I can propose a workaround. Try this:

```
Manipulate[
 graficoTr = 
  Labeled[ListPlot[
    Table[{dataPerCompound[[i, All, 9]], 
       dataPerCompound[[i, All, 2]]}\[Transpose], {i, 
      Length[compoundNameRight]}], 
    PlotLegends -> 
     Placed[PointLegend[colours1, 
       Style[#, par1] & /@ compoundNameRight, 
       LegendMarkers -> markers, LegendLayout -> {"Column", 3}], 
      Right], PlotMarkers -> Evaluate[{#, par2} & /@ markers], 
    PlotStyle -> colours1, ImageSize -> 500, 
    Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, FrameStyle -> 15, 
    PlotRange -> All], {Rotate[
     Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Sigma]\), \ \(exp\)]\)(N\
\[CenterDot]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(m\), \(-1\)]\))", 15], 90 Degree], 
    Style[Row[{Style["Tr", 15], Spacer[x]}], 
     ScriptBaselineShifts -> {0, .5}, SingleLetterItalics -> False, 
     "TraditionalForm"]}, {Left, Bottom}, 
   FrameMargins -> {{-8, 0}, {0, 0}}], {x, 0, 400}]
```

and choose a proper value of x.

Have fun!